# puppeteer: How to wait for pages in SPA's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to navigate through an SPA with puppeteer, the problem I am facing here is that I am unable to wait for the page to load then proceed with my program.

I fill a form and then click submit, depending on the contents of the form, different pages can be loaded so I can't use `page.waitFor(Selector)` as there can be many different pages depending on the input.

I tried using `waitUntil:` load, networkidle2, networkidle0, domcontentloaded but all of them trigger before the elements are loaded.

The page I am trying to automate is [Link](https://icheck.sita.aero/iCheckWebAI/). (If you want to check for yourself, then choose booking reference and fill out random details and press continue.)

After choosing "booking-reference" in the link I fill in the details with puppeteer and then press the continue button, What I cannot figure out is how to wait for the page to be completely loaded without relying on selectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen to history.pushstate with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900248/how-to-listen-to-history-pushstate-with-puppeteer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should know what those pages are and use `Promise.race` with `page.waitFor` for each page, like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="element"></div>
    <button id="button">load</button>

    <script>
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.getElementById('element').innerHTML =
          '<div id="element' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1)  + '"></div>';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  await page.click('#button');

  const element = await Promise.race([
    page.waitFor('#element1'),
    page.waitFor('#element2'),
    page.waitFor('#element3')
  ]);

  console.log(await (await element.getProperty('id')).jsonValue());
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, also is there any way to know which won the race? I mean which element came up?

Comment: `Promise.race` return only one element: the fastes one - in your case element which distinguishes what page is loaded. I'm detecting in line `await (await element.getProperty('id')).jsonValue()` what ID of this element is, next it's up to you what you do with this information.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a quick answer, here's the main code:

```
await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), el.click()]);
```

...where `el` is a link that points to another page in the SPA and `click` is a an action that triggers navigation. See below for details.

---

I agree that `waitFor` isn't too helpful if you can't rely on page content. Even if you can, in most cases it seems like a less desirable approach than naturally reacting to the navigation. Luckily, `page.waitForNavigation` does work on SPAs. Here's a minimal, complete example of navigating between pages using a click event on a link (the same should work for a form submission) on a [tiny vanilla SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041356/6243352) which uses the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (`index.html` below).

#### `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const nav = `<a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/about">About</a> | 
                   <a href="/contact">Contact</a>`;
      const routes = {
        "/": `<h1>Home</h1>${nav}<p>Welcome home!</p>`,
        "/about": `<h1>About</h1>${nav}<p>This is a tiny SPA</p>`,
      };
      const render = path => {
        document.body.innerHTML = routes[path] || `<h1>404</h1>${nav}`;
        document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/"]').forEach(el => 
          el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            const {pathname: path} = new URL(evt.target.href);
            window.history.pushState({path}, path, path);
            render(path);
          })
        );
      };
      window.addEventListener("popstate", e =>
        render(new URL(window.location.href).pathname)
      );
      render("/");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### `index.js`:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const text = s => page.$eval(s, el => el.textContent);

  // navigate to the home page for the SPA and print the contents
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8000");
  console.log(page.url()); // => http://localhost:8000/
  console.log(await text("p")); // => Welcome home!

  // navigate to the about page via the link
  const a = await page.waitForSelector("text/About");
  await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), a.click()]);

  // show proof that we're on the about page
  console.log(page.url()); // => http://localhost:8000/about
  console.log(await text("p")); // => This is a tiny SPA
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

#### Sample run:

```
$ python3 -m http.server &
$ node index
http://localhost:8000/
Welcome home!
http://localhost:8000/about
This is a tiny SPA
```

---

If the `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), el.click()]);` pattern seems strange, see [this issue thread](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1412) which explains the [gotcha](https://duklee.net/posts/puppeteer-gotchas/) that the intuitive

```
await page.waitForNavigation(); 
await el.click();
```

causes a race condition.

The same thing as the `Promise.all` shown above can be done with:

```
const navPromise = page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 1000});
await el.click();
await navPromise;
```

---

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52900794/6243352) for more on navigating SPAs with Puppeteer including hash routers.

Comment: I see you're active in both puppeteer and playwright tags, so hope you know... I've seen this weird click-then-navigate behaviour for playwright's `WaitForURLAsync` too. Is this something you reckon could manifest in playwright (it's a fork after all)?

Comment: @lonix I would ask a new question with a minimal example of the problem. `waitForURL` is supposed to be free of race conditions and works differently than `waitForNavigation()` discussed in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for single page application to wait for navigation and get the response status and data. Whether `fetch` or `XHR` is being used to do the `Ajax` request, the main idea should be the same. The following example demonstrates it with `fetch`

```js
  async spaClick (selector) {
    const res = await this.eval(selector, el => {
      window.originalFetch = window.originalFetch || window.fetch
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.fetch = function (...args) {
          return window.originalFetch.apply(this, args)
            .then(async response => {
              resolve({
                status: response.status,
                data: await response.clone().text()
              })

              return response
            })
        }

        el.click()
      })
    })

    if (!res) throw new Error('spaClick() Navigation triggered before eval resolves!')
    return res
  }
```

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'http://www.faalkaart.nl';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // await Promise.all([
    //   page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
    //   page.click('selector-that-triggers-navigation'),
    // ]);
    const response = await spaClick('selector-that-triggers-navigation')
    console.log(response) // {status, data}
    await browser.close();
})();
```